# prevent automatic scroll when text is inserted into contenteditable div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Issue present in **Chrome ONLY**.

I am experiencing undesirable browser behaviour where upon typing into a contenteditable div that increases its height upwards - the browser appears to automatically scroll upwards. Is there any way to prevent the scrolling behaviour as it leading to undesirable UX.

Please see the example below that illustrates the issue where upon first **scrolling down** and attempting to **type until a new line is created** inside the `#bottom-child` that contains *Insert text* will cause the scrollbar to automatically go up. **It is easier to replicate this issue in the Full page mode that is selectable after running the snippet**.

```css
#parent {
  height: 2000px;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#top-child {
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Please scroll down a little bit and type in text in the 'Insert text' area to see the automatic scroll.
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-child"></div>
    <div id="bottom-child" contenteditable="true">Insert text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work-around to this problem where we can identify that an automatic scroll is about to take place and programmatically force scroll to the original position. This is done by getting the original *scrollY* on `keydown` and then getting the new *scrollY* on `input` which is fired directly after `keydown`. If they don't match scroll to original *scrollY*.

However this is relatively *hacky* and other alternatives are welcome.

**Solution:**

```
function preventAutomaticScrollUpOnNewLine(bottomChildDiv) {
    let scrollY;
    bottomChildDiv.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
        scrollY = window.scrollY;
    });
    bottomChildDiv.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (scrollY !== window.scrollY) {
            window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});
        }
    });
}
```